# NOT IN operator for filter in dataset SQL Server Reporting Services 2016/Report Builder 3

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Does anyone know how to do "NOT IN" as the operator for a filter in a dataset?

Comment: Please elaborate your question more.

Comment: So I am trying to create a filter in a dataset. However the tool only has the IN set operator. I would like to write it to filter something like this - NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: Screenshot - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1olxLn1XRFPu7xG_2DogShfnz3mDRqKgS

Answer (score 0):

OK. So I was working in DB2 and the MS Report Builder does not allow you to use the Query Designer for that database - via odbc or OLEDB.

I pointed my connect to SQL Server and attempted this on a test table in the database. The "NOT IN" filter is built in there, but needs to be handled using a parameter (if you want it to be dynamic obviously).

I worked out the set logic myself in sql and passed in a report parameter. This works.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the "Join" operator within the filter

[Here is a detailed example](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28321.ssrs-simulating-not-in-and-not-like-functionality-in-ssrs-filter-expressions.aspx)

Comment: This is an excellent solution, although certainly this is a little bit of a cludgey workaround. I don't see how Microsoft could overlook such important operations. I assume it's because the reporting paradigm is antiquated and they are focused on Power BI and dashboards.